# div-tooltip - same on stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i mouseover on my nick in stackoverflow on top page that show me new menu with     * activity
    * privileges
    * logout etc. how can i make it? i maked something:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#ONE {
    background-color: #888;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#TWO {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#THREE {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
}
#four {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#TWO").click(
        function()
        {
            $("#THREE").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="ONE">
    <div id="TWO">
    </div>

    <div id="four">
    </div>

    <div id="THREE">
    </div>
</div>
```

sample image: http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/3885/threej.png

1. default
2. click for blue div
3. how can i it make?

Comment: You seem to have made something, but it looks nothing like the one on SO. You *do* know you can just copy the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript from the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to make the yellow `div` appear up beside the blue one, as you have it in the third mockup? If that's the case, then:

You'll want to read up on [CSS Positioning](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position). In a nutshell, to make the yellow `div` sit over everything like that, it needs to take `position: absolute;` It'll be positioned in relation to it's nearest ancestor that has positioning, so set `#ONE` to `position: relative;`

So:

```
#ONE {
  position: relative;
}
#THREE {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 25%;
}
```

This will make the top-left of `#THREE` shift to the far right of and a quarter of the way down `#ONE`. The absolute positioning also takes it out of the flow of the document, allowing it to overlap other elements.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I read `#ONE` as the blue one, not `#TWO`. Set `left: 50px; top: 10px;` on `#THREE`: http://jsfiddle.net/wQJ3j/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position elements on top of each other, use `position`: `relative` or `absolute`. If you want it to stick to a position on your window regardless of if you scroll, use `fixed`.

After defining the `position`, you can define `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to position it where you want. To simulate the 3rd image in your example, you could add:

```
position:relative;
top: -220px;
left:50px;
```

to your `#THREE` elements CSS, like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Axjgf/

Comment: This will  be quite fragile: the degree of relative positioning needed will change with the displayed size of `#TWO`. Also, you'll be left with a big gap in the page where `#THREE` came from. `relative` positioning moves the element, but everything else on the page behaves as if it were still where it would otherwise have been.

Comment: @gisinior, you can set the opacity with cross browser support using `.css({ opacity: 0.5 });` example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Axjgf/7/ @marramgrass, he has defined the size for `#TWO` and the container where all elements were positioned is of fixed size as well, so the gap is there regardless.

Comment: You are, of course, correct, but based on the rather vague code sample and even more vague mock up, I was going for the more flexible solution.